# Correct use of HashMap

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, adapter

I have a ListView with all the applications installed on the device. When I click on one of them part of the contextual action bar to perform operations on selected items. To store the name of the application package and the position in the list I'm using a HashMap. So I wrote this code in my adapter ListView.

Comment: If you want to run code on each item, put that code inside the loop.  Do you understand what the code you wrote is doing?

Comment: you don not have 1- App01 2- App02 3- App03 in your hash map. You have App01-1  , App02-2 , App03-3? is this ok for you? So you will retrieve index of the list, you probably don't want that?

Comment: Hello, of course I know what you're doing. Thank you.

Comment: @user3103764 Please don't edit your question to this useless form. You mention code and there's none. There's no question either. I rolled back your edit once but it seems you re-edited the question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your log is outside the loop, if you want it to print every time put the logging line inside.

```
public void getHashMap() {
    int value = 0;
    String key = "";
    Iterator myVeryOwnIterator = mHashMap.keySet().iterator();
    while(myVeryOwnIterator.hasNext()) {

        key=(String)myVeryOwnIterator.next();
        value= mHashMap.get(key);
        Log.d("", "Retrieving value "+key+value);

    }
}
```

Comment: no problem, just dont forget to mark this as the answer.